# Javascript 'Interactive Map' working intermittently on Chrome

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I have created this map (in adobe edge - it uses javascript):
http://lpff.org.uk/Book-a-Pitch/All

It loads first time in Safari (mac). On Chrome (mac) it -sometimes- doesn't work the first load, if you click refresh then it works.

On the first load in Chrome I get these Javascript errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bindElementAction' of undefined index_edgeActions.js:16
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'okToLaunchComposition'

How can I get it to work first time - and what's causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: I'd expect some script is being called, before the asset containing a referenced method is called. With a cached version, it's loaded fast enough to be all good. Try adding an on ready delay to your code using the map.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue most of the times when I was trying edge. Decided to quit using it and script on my own!

Comment: Such behavior might also be due to javascript files order: index_edgeAction.js that contains the bind function is loaded very late on my chrome and after the loaded event fires (check it out in Network tool of google chrome). However, it worked fine for me... You could try to reference edge script upper in the script list

Comment: Thanks - I've never had this problem with Edge before (though this is the first time I am embedding something in a page with it)